# What causes FontMetrics stringWidth to return different values on different machines?

Tags: java, fonts, fontmetrics

The following code prints different values when ran on different machines:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Main {

     public static void main(String []args){
        Graphics g = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY).getGraphics();
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
        
        int width = fontMetrics.stringWidth("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.");
        
        System.out.println(width);
     }
}
```

I was expecting the output of the program to be the same if I run the code on different computers, but I ran it on two machines and one prints `606` while the other prints `699`.

What can cause this behavior? Does string width calculation depend on the environment? (jdk, operating system, etc?)

Comment: I also get 606 using JDK11 on windows 11.  I don't use any scaling. Maybe scaling causes the difference?

Comment: @camickr I do use scaling, and I get 606 as well (Java 8, 11 and 17, Windows 11). But given there is no displaying involved here, I would be surprised if it considered scaling. More likely the difference is specific to the OS (e.g. slightly different variants or versions of Arial, or different font rendering pipelines, ligatures enabled/disabled, etc).

Comment: Note that  you're not loading the same font on both computers. You're loading whatever the system has installed with the name `Arial`. Fonts, just like all other software, have versions so if things look different, or behave differently, step 1 is to check the fonts on those machines. On my Windows 10 machine, for example, "Arial" is Monotype's Arial version 7.00 from 2017. If you to _guarantee_ the same font metrics across devices, you'd have to bundle the actual font file and then load that (but that's illegal for Arial, so you'd have to find a free to use font instead)

Comment: `new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10)` loads a **10 point** font.  Not 10 pixels, 10 points.  A point is ¹⁄₇₂ of an inch.  The exact number of pixels are needed to comprise 10 points will depend on the monitor in use.  (And yes, the system, and therefore Java, usually has access to that information.)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you, this clarifies it. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you're not loading the same font on both computers. You're loading "whatever the system has installed" that resolves through the name Arial. Just like other software, fonts are versioned, so if things look or behave differently between machines you want to check which actual fonts are being used on those machines.

For example, on my Windows 10 machine, "Arial" is Monotype's Arial v7.00 from 2017. On an older version of Windows Arial could be v6.89 (win8) or 5.22 (win7), which may have subtly or radically different text metrics depending on the text you're typesetting.

If you to need to guarantee the same font metrics across devices, you'd have to bundle the actual font file your application and then load your font from that file instead of loading it by name for the OS to handle.

However: remember that fonts at exactly the same as any other software in that they have licenses, and you can't just distribute them without permission. Arial, for example, may not be freely distributed without a license from Monotype, so you'd have to find a free-to-distribute font to use instead. (And note that for legal purposes, a free font without a license is not free, but "you have no idea what the license is so you might be breaking the law simply by downloading it at all". Real free fonts come with an open source software license like the SIL font license that explicitly allow you to redistribute them)